# How to update one of the column of database column data type from varbinary to varchar and update the entity as well DBFirst approach?

Tags: database, entity-framework, model-view-controller

database is already existing. I have started working on some crud operations using entity framework. No I want to change one of the cloumn data type from varbinary to varchar in db and similarly update in Entity model. Ho to do i do that. ?

From the sources i got to know that, First I need to update the table using sql query and then in VS right click on edmx model and select Update Model from Database. Is it right? I tried but still changes are not reflecting in model. Please help!